# Example app for AngularJS IE9 URL rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

Is anyone aware of an example app that uses URL rewriting on the server side (preferably Rails), in order to accommodate AngularJS on IE9?

In other words, I'm serving an app at `/v2/challenges/new`, which gets changed to `#/v2/challenges/new` in IE9's location bar, which in turn just redirects to `"/"`. What am I supposed to do on the server side to accommodate this?

Comment: Rewrite everything to your app's index.html? What webserver do you use with RoR, apache? nginx? Do you set $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ?

Comment: The app is hosted on Heroku, so the webserver is Unicorn. But I should be able to do it just in Rails, right?

Comment: Also, yes, html5Mode is set to true.